# Replot function which depends on time, Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot, qt6

I'm writing a study project and I need to plot a function that depends on real-time. I used [QCustomPlot](https://www.qcustomplot.com). This plot should start drawing when I pressed a button.
So I've wrote next code

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_restart_clicked()
{
... 
my_timer->restart();
/* Set up and initialize the graph plotting timer */ 
connect(&timer_plot, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(realtimePlot())); // where QTimer timer_plot
timer_plot.start(20); 
}
```

`realtimePlot()` looks like

```cpp
void MainWindow::realtimePlot()
{

    ui->widget->graph(0)->data()->clear();

    double key = my_timer->elapsed() / 1000.0;
    static double lastPointKey = 0;

    if(key - lastPointKey > 0.002)
    {
        for (auto& iter : x) {
            ui->widget->graph(0)->addData(iter, sin(iter+key));
        }
        lastPointKey = key;
    }
    ui->widget->replot();
}
```

And it works properly, but when I want to restart the plot and pressed the button again there is a delay before the plot will be drawn and it increases with each click on the button, and the animation of the plot becomes less and less smooth. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR1eU.jpg) you can watch my screencast with the problem.

Code for real-time plot I took from [here](https://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/realtimedatademo)

And `MainWindow()`

```cpp
QVector<double> x;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->widget->addGraph();
    ui->widget->xAxis->setRange(0, 20);
    my_timer->start();
    h = 0.05;
    x.push_back(0);
    for (int i=1; i<=20/h; i++)
    {
        x.push_back(i*h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GhasemRamezani I added code for MainWindow, the truth is that I don't know how a minimal reproducible example for QtApp should look

Comment: @deethereal Then read the links

Comment: @eyllanesc I've read it but for "reproducible" example QtApp requires at least 6 standard files, I've provided all code, that I use except for mainwindow.h, mainwindow.ui and main.cpp. I also recorded and shared a video with the problem. Is there not enough information?

Comment: Why do you connect the timer when the button is pressed? I would expect that the wiring is done initially on creation. Then the button should only start the timer.

Comment: @ypnos Yeap, that was not logically correct, thank you for your note

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the problem. It was `my_timer->restart()`, but I still don't know why it causes to delay. According to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#start-1) this function just stops and starts the timer.

P.S. Depends on compiler it may not works. For example **MinGW** doesn't work with this solution unlike **clang**